# Template is not working in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I just started working in [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

In that I created a simple example of showing the values in the template using the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Now I want to create some advanced example of showing the values of a user in the template using the model thing

[image]

Now my model is (EditProfileModel.js):

```
window.EditProfileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

constructor : function(attributes, options) {
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
},
defaults : {
    id : '',
    firstName : '',
    lastName : '',
},
urlRoot: 'rest/editProfile'
});
```

EditProfileView.js :

```
window.EditProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

template : 'tpl/EditProfileTpl.html',
el: content,

initialize:function () {
    this.render();
},

events: {

},

render:function () {
    var $this = this;

    var editProfileModel = new EditProfileModel({   
        id:this.model.get('id')
    });

    //GET editProfile/id
    editProfileModel.fetch({
        success : function(model){
            //console.log("I am fetch " + JSON.stringify(model));

            TemplateManager.get($this.template, function(template){

                console.log($(template).html());
                var html = _.template($(template).html(),{user : model});

                $this.$el.html(html);


                return $this;
            });
        }
    });
},

});
```

and main.js with router thing is:

```
.....
routes : {
    "profile/:id" : "editProfile"
},

editProfile : function(id){

    var $this = this;

    $this.model = new EditProfileModel({
        id:id
    });

    $('#content').html(
        new EditProfileView({
            model: $this.model
        })
    );
}


......
```

*TemplateManager is just a javascript code that fetches the template on demand and stores it in the array and send the same template back if requested second time from its memory.(I got its code [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/09/asynchronously-load-html-templates-for-backbone-views/))*

But its showing like this :
[image]

(see the textbox value it should be **admin** as it is returned from the server)

Please help me, this is really wierd..................

:(

this is the html that is coming from the server (template):::

```
<div>
    <form id="frmEditProfile" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="firstName">FirstName</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="firstName" value="&lt;%=model.get('firstName')%&gt;" autofocus="autofocus">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="lastName">LastName</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" type="submit">
                    <i class="icon-ok"></i> Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried decoding the HTML template before injecting the model into it?

Answer (score 1):

TemplateManager ? Did you see that in the link you post, Derrick mentions it was a bad idea ?

Anyway: you logged the $template.html(), you just need to log the model, then you should be able to see what is wrong in the console.

Comment: what is the value of $template.html(), what is the one of model ?

Comment: please see the edited part of the question I appended the code of the template as well in the question

Comment: I cannot see any Underscore delimiters in your template. Look, this is how to use it: `_.template('Hello <%= user.name %>', {user: {name: 'Doe', nick: 'John'}})`. More info [here](http://underscorejs.org/#template). So check both your template and the data you send to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding the HTML entities that comes back from your `TemplateManager`.

```
var data = model.toJSON();
var tmpl = $("<div />").html($(template).html()).text();
var html = _.template(tmpl, {firstName: data.firstName});
```

Also change your template to this:

```
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="firstName" 
    value="<%= firstName %>" autofocus="autofocus">...
```

Comment: Actually I just printed the model that is in the callback of fetch and found that it has some other things as well, may be that is a part of backbone, when I created the basic model with those 3 variables(firstName,lastName,id ie used in template) I got the thing but I am not understanding the difference

Comment: OK, see my modified answer. Remove the `model.get('firstName')` implementation from your template since that's not how template works.